# What is the recommended way to connect TP4056 charger module to NodeMCU v2

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, lipo, nodemcu

I want to power a NodeMCU v2 with a 3.7v 2000 mAh LiPo battery and charge the battery with the NodeMCU connected (i.e. under load). After looking into various forums, I ordered a TP4056 battery charger module with overcharging protection to safely charge the battery. [image]

However, I am really confused about the recommended way of connecting the TP4056 to the NodeMCU. I have seen similar questions in various forums online, either without an accepted answer or proposing entirely different approaches for achieving this. For instance, [Power ESP32/ESP8266 with Solar Panels](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/power-esp32-esp8266-solar-panels-battery-level-monitoring/) suggests the use of a low dropout voltage regulator along with a capacitor while [Using TP4056 module to charge battery while load remains connected](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416231/using-tp4056-module-to-charge-battery-while-load-remains-connected) suggests the use of a relay and MT3608 DC-DC boost converter. Some forums also mention the use of schottky diodes. What will happen if I connect the TP4056 directly to the NodeMCU. Can someone give a technical explanation and suggest the recommended way to achieve this?

I am an electronics noob. So, kindly bear with any stupidity in the above question! I will be glad to provide any more details if required.

Comment: from what source?

Comment: what is the output voltage of the TP4056? ... what power supply voltage does the NodeMCU require?

Comment: @jsotola From my understanding, TP4056 will output the voltage of the battery connected to it, so in this case 3.7 V (4.2V on full charge), and the NodeMCU's operating voltage is 3.3V.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I suppose you want to know how I expect to charge the battery? I would like to charge via the micro-usb connector in the TP4056 board

Comment: I have no idea how you want, but avoid rapid charge and consider more batteries than trying to use 100% capacity each time.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475787/laptop-batteries-charging-myths-long-life-or-short-life