# Why does the step up boost module say its for 3.7V but has an input of 4.5V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-up

I want to use this Step Up Converter (Boost Module), ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0B7JGJ67J/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B7JGJ67J)), to power a 12V .15A blower fan using a 3.7V 2500 mAh battery. The step converter says that it is for a 3.7V supply but in the description, it says that the input is from 4.5V to 8V (which is higher than the 3.7V of the battery). What is happening here?

Comment: Welcome! Input would be for the charger side of things, which is made for 5 V USB.

Comment: That makes perfect and obvious sense. Thank you.

Comment: Beware: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/429561/1743  Unless you can get a proper schematic and verify that the charge current measurement isn't being affected by load currents, you should not use that module.

Comment: Because: you are buying electronics from bad sources like Amazon, whom have no quality concerns whatsoever. Buy from serious electronics vendors instead: Digikey/Mouser/RS/Farnell etc etc.